# How can I get black/blue/green player cards in FIFA World?

Tags: fifa-world

I have been playing **FIFA World** for last 3-4 months and have seen some other player cards which are not normal bronze/silver/gold. They are colored in either black or blue or green etc..

[image]

*Example - Blue card of Rooney*

While searching for them online I got the [description](http://answers.ea.com/t5/General/Fifa-World-Beta-Blue-Black-Red-Players-Card/td-p/3465537) of this cards. But I did not find any idea or approach about how can I get one of them.

Also I don't want to bid or buy them from  ***transfer market*** as they are very costly for me. There must be some other ways to get those rare players.

Games like *FIFA 14* and *FIFA 15* may have these same things but do not know well about those as I didn't play any of them. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's just luck -__- you find them in packs or buy them. Simple as that.